# Why aren't the numbers going up in order?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

When `Add Item` is clicked, it is expected that the items will be created in order, starting from number 3.

But strangely, 4 times are skipped and created.

That is, they are created in the order of 3~, 5~, 6~.

This can be a very basic question in react. Can you tell me why at some point the value of 4 was skipped?

```js
import { useState, Children } from "react";

let index = 3;

export default function App() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState<string[]>(["1~", "2~"]);

  function handleClick() {
    setItems((prev) => [...prev, `${index}~`]);
    index++;
  }

  return (
    <>
      <main>
        <div>
          <button onClick={handleClick}>Add Item</button>
        </div>
        <div>{Children.toArray(items.map((item) => <div>{item}</div>))}</div>
      </main>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I explain what happened step by step:

1. On line 3, you assign `index` to `3`. So `index` is `3` now. It's a global variable.
2. On line 6, set an initial array in `useState`with 2 element. So `items` has **2** item right now.
3. On line 9, you use `setItem` with a global variable that is `3`. You must notice that [`useState()` hook did works async](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#why-is-setstate-giving-me-the-wrong-value).
4. On line 10, here is the point. The `index` was global. But after increasing here, it converted to local variable and [component observed on it](https://dev.to/yezyilomo/global-state-management-in-react-with-global-variables-and-hooks-state-management-doesn-t-have-to-be-so-hard-2n2c). Now `index` is 4 and observed. **Again**, `useState()` hook did works async.
5. `handleClick` function called again. But this time first `index` increased then `setItems` works **(Again : useState() hook did works async)**

Try this:

```
import { useState, Children } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState(["1~", "2~"]);

  function handleClick() {
    setItems((prev) => [...prev, `${prev.length + 1}~`]);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <main>
        <div>
          <button onClick={handleClick}>Add Item</button>
        </div>
        <div>{Children.toArray(items.map((item) => <div>{item}</div>))}</div>
      </main>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: First thanks for the solution. May I know the logical reason why item 4~ was not added to the question I posted? I'm very curious as to why.

Comment: Thank you for your kind explanation. I have additional questions. I already knew that the useState() hook works asynchronously, but thanks to your explanation I learned something new. When a global variable is used in a functional component, is there a mechanism to convert it into a local variable of the component that used the variable? I would like to find out more related to that mechanism.

Comment: @박경은 It's 1M$ question.